# Sort by image resolution (dimensions)

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, display-resolution

Which program has a function to sort images by their pixel size / resolution / dimensions.

Very strange but even so powerful DigiKam doesn't have so simple function.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I've no idea how this performs but ImageMagick has an `identify` application that I've got to learn over the last ten minutes. Better than anything, it has a `-format` argument where you can do maths!

```
find -iname '*.jpg' -exec identify -format "%[fx:w*h] %i\n" {} \+ | sort -g
```

Unfortunately, if you get above a certain size, you get scientific notation (eg 1.2*10^3) instead of an integer back from identify. Thankfully sort has a `-g` argument that will parse them out.

On the same files here, this version (not forking out to Perl) only take 60% of the time the Perl version does. That's not to say Perl is slow, but going into perl and subshelling back out is an unnecessary complication that's slowing things down (I think).

Mine still isn't ideal. Needing to parse numbers back to integers for sorting is fairly slow. Ideally you'd  do this all internally in one language where the size remains as an integer throughout... But the above is the shortest, sharpest one-liner I can do.

Comment: Are you sure `sort -g` handles scientific notation correctly? I ask because `(echo 1.45e+06; echo 1.15e+06; echo 1.44e+06; echo 5; echo 2) | sort -g` returns a curious order (I tested using bash)

Comment: @SylvainPineau does it still return something strange? It sorts correctly (2,5,1.15e+06,1.44e+06,1.45e+06) for me.

Comment: @terdon it depends on the locale, tested with `LC_ALL=C` it works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a command-line tool, the following command will sort image files where the highest resolution comes first:

```
find . -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.jpg" | perl -e '$f=sub{eval(`identify -format %w*%h ${\quotemeta(shift)} 2>/dev/null`)};print sort{$f->($b)<=>$f->($a)}<>'
```

I'm basically sorting the files using `perl` [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) sub-subroutine where the key here is to call the `identify` command and eval its formatted output.

`identify` is available with the `imagemagick` package:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

**UPDATE**:

The following command will also output the resolution:

```
find . -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.jpg" | perl -e '$f=sub{`identify -format %w*%h ${\quotemeta(shift)} 2>/dev/null`};chomp&&print "$_\t".$f->($_) for sort{eval($f->($b))<=>eval($f->($a))}<>'
```

Example:

```
./foo bar.png   1600*900
./baz.png       1600*900
./img_0004.jpg  1280*720
./img_0006.jpg  1280*720
./img_0001.jpg  1280*720
./img_0003.jpg  1280*720
./img_0002.jpg  1280*720
./img_0005.jpg  1280*720
./launcher.png  385*632
./textfield.png 402*329
./foo2.png      202*229
```

Comment: I have imagemagick already installed. I enter your command in the folder with jpg and png images, and there are also xmp files, and it shows me some errors which I don't understand:

'`identify.im6: unable to open image ./estrada: No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
identify.im6: no decode delegate for this image format ./estrada @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.`'

If thats important, filenames doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: You have to use the first `find` command correctly to filter only images otherwise `identify` will fail with this error. I got it when I tried `find . -iname "*"`

Comment: I've added support for filenames containing spaces. Please try again the new command

Comment: The snippet to output resolution is great, thanks! It helps to separate each image with a newline:

`find . -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.jpg" | perl -e '$f=sub{\`identify -format %w*%h ${\quotemeta(shift)} 2>/dev/null\`};chomp&&print "$_\t".$f->($_)."\n" for sort{eval($f->($b))<=>eval($f->($a))}<>'`

Answer (score 2):

### Using `find`, `file --mime-type`, `identify`, `awk` and `sort`

Using `file --mime-type` we find *all images*, even without an extension.

The one-line at the end of this answer has a problem with newlines in the file name. Therefore here an other version:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file --brief --mime-type "$0" |\
grep -q ^image/ && identify -format "%[fx:w*h] %i\n" "$0"' {} \; |\
sort -g
```

*Sample output*

```
26696 ./OWoHp.png
37975 ./hUXnc.png
47275 ./foo
bar.png
```

This is the file with the newline in the filename:

```
47275 ./foo
bar.png
```

Many thanks [@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon), [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) and [@glennjackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) for the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212701/107084).

---

*Old version with a problem if the filename contains newlines*

```
find . -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -I{} file --mime-type {} | \
    awk -F$"\0" -F": " '/image/ {print $1}' | \
    xargs -I{} identify -format "%[fx:w*h] %i\n" {} | \
    sort -g
```

---

*Sample output*

```
9216 ./.face
27918 ./Unbenannt.png
1.0368e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/14-13.jpg
1.57292e+07 ./Images/Wallpapers/wallpaper_19.jpg
1.57292e+07 ./Images/Wallpapers/wallpaper_22.jpg
1.92e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/black (10).jpg
2.304e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/1920x1200.jpg
2.304e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/1920x1200_Seria_Lunar-Melodies.png
2.304e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/Anime_girl_129177.jpg
2.304e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/wallpaper-1802661.jpg
2.304e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/wallpaper-264390.jpg
3.14368e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/14 - 2.jpg
3.6864e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/14-1.jpg
4.096e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/wallpaper-2850337.jpg
4.096e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/wt4NRqA.jpg
7.0969e+06 ./Images/Wallpapers/14 - 1.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but here's my version with `find`,`exiftool`,and `sort`:

`find . -exec exiftool -S -t -q -FileName -ImageSize  {} + | sort -k2n,2`

It's a bit slow, but works. Sample output:

```
$ find Downloads -exec exiftool -S -t -q -FileName -ImageSize  {} + | sort -k2n,2 

1433695350670.jpg   1600x1000
1433695350670.jpg   1600x1000
1434999385912.jpg   2212x3318
1434999385912.jpg   2212x3318
1433524966694.jpg   2688x1520
1433524966694.jpg   2688x1520
1433525301504.jpg   2688x1520
1433525301504.jpg   2688x1520
```

Answer (score 1):

[Geeqie](http://geeqie.org/) can sort by image size.

```
sudo apt install geeqie
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort PNG images and store them in subfolder according to their size (width x height):

```
for f in *.png; do \
  s=$(identify -format "%wx%h" $f); \
  test -d $s || mkdir $s; \
  mv $f $s/$f; \
done
```

Explanation: `identify -format "%wx%h" filename.png` returns the image with x height, so store it in variable `s`, create a folder if not yet existing, then move the image to that directory; and do that in a loop fo all local PNG files.

Answer (score 0):

Oli's answer works. Here is a modification to list minimum of width and height

```sh
find * -type f -exec identify -format "%[fx:w>h?h:w] %i\n" {} \+ | sort -g
```